# Cant select "this" in my conditional function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

the following function is working well, but I cant select "this" element. Whats wrong?

```
$('.req').each(function(){
    if ($("input").attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required]") && $("input").val().length === 0) {
       $(this).addClass("warning");
    } 
});
```

Comment: `if` conditions do not have a scope, hence `this` will refer to the scope of whatever block the `if` is contained in. We cannot offer any more help given the limited code sample you've shown.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's very hard to say what is wrong

Comment: wait, so you want to add the class "warning" to the inputs match the criteria?

Comment: Also note that `$("input").attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required]")` is a setter which will return a jQuery object and hence will always coerce to `true` in your `if` condition. As such the logic itself is flawed.

Comment: I just updated the code with some more specific scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok as said in the comments, this is really vague without further context. however, assuming that you want to add class "warning" to all inputs who match your criteria, I suspect you need to do something like this:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("data-validation-engine","validate[required]") && $(this).val().length === 0)
    $(this).addClass("warning"); 
});
```

for example:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'number')
      $(this).addClass("warning"); 
  });
});
```

```css
.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the `warning` class to all empty inputs with the the `data-validation-engine` attribute set to `validate[required]`, you can use the below code.

It selects all the inputs with the correct attribute and value. It then filters that result, leaving the matching inputs that are empty. It then adds the `warning` class to those inputs.

```
$("input[data-validation-engine='validate[required]']").filter(function() {
    return !this.value.length;
}).addClass("warning");​
```